# Proof that $ f'(x)=0 $ has $n-1$ roots

Tags: calculus

I am given $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(x-n)$.
I am obliged to proof that for $n \ge 1$, the equation $ f'(x)=0 $ has $n-1$ roots.

I think I have to somehow use Rolle's theorem to proof that.
I will be glad for any help and tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hints**:

- The original function has exactly $n$ roots, at $1, 2, 3, ..., n$.
- Consider Rolle's Theorem on the intervals $[1, 2]$, $[2, 3]$, ..., $[n - 1, n]$.
- The derivative is a polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$.

Can you see how to put it together?

Comment: When I consider Rolle's Theorem on the intervals I am able to say that there are exactly $n-1$ points $c$ that $f'(c) = 0 $ But I do not understand that it implies that $f'(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ has $n-1$ roots?.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand this. Thank you

Comment: @MarcinMajewski You're very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

[rolle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)

$f(k)=f(k+1)$, $k=1,2,\dotsc,n-1$, so there exists a $\alpha_k\in(k.k+1)$ such that

$$f'(\alpha_k)=0$$